# Пишу приложение "Викторина" на java под Android

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Пишу приложение "Викторина" на java под Android.

Возник момент, который я не очень понимаю: Мне нужно написать приложение, в котором есть окно с вопросом и 4 вариантами ответа, как только пользователь выбирает ответ и нажимает ответить, программа переходит к следующему вопросу.

Если бы я писал на java под ПК, я бы создал два класса:
1) Главный класс, который нужен для запуска программы и работы со вторым классом
2) Класс, в котором есть 5 полей (экземпляров) класса, одно поле для передачи в него текста вопроса и ещё 4 для передачи ответов.

Затем я бы создал в главном классе объекты второго (столько объектов, сколько вопросов) и передавал бы всем их переменным вопрос и варианты ответов.

Также в главном классе я бы написал метода кнопки "ответ", который отвечает за переход от одного объекта к другому и так, пока они не закончатся

Теперь про Android: под него я только начинаю писать, поэтому имею весьма смутное представление даже о том, как составить алгоритм программы.

Насколько я понимаю, мне необходимо аналогично с ПК версией создать две активности и, при помощи интента, передавать данные так же как с объектами. Или может для этих целей лучше использовать фрагмент, прикреплённый к активности.

Буду благодарен, если подскажите алгоритм выполнения данной задачи на Android Studio

Comment: в книгах П.Дейтела "android для разработчиков" и Б.Харди "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" есть очень подробные примеры игр-викторин с разбором и описанием. Рекомендую прочитать эти книги и у вас не останется смутных пониманий

Comment: Большое спасибо!